# Record video and send it to server

Tags: camera, video, storage, web-server, video-streaming

I want to record a video, and stream it directly to the server while recording (i.e. the video should be saved on the server, not necessarily locally on the Android device). How can this be accomplished? The built-in camera app does not seem to offer this feature.

Comment: Please note that *Is there an app for X* questions are off topic on our site (see the [FAQ] for details). You should be open to all solutions for an issue :) So forgive me a little re-phrasing (feel free to edit it again if I missed something).

Comment: You're welcome! Though in some cases it seems pretty clear the answer will be "use this-and-that app", we try to keep our minds open. In the 9 months I'm here with ASE, I've seen a lot of surprising answers and solutions I've never thought of -- so I stopped thinking about something being "impossible" (and switched that to "unlikely, but who knows" :)

Comment: Partial solution: [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en). I use this app to have fun from time to time. You can view live feed by accessing the phone's ip, it does **not** upload to a server.

Comment: I am also finding the same solution for record and directly upload to server. Can anyone have solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic solution to your problem would be the following:

1. Set up any one of the IP Camera apps on the Play store.
2. Access the IP Camera app's web interface via the server.
3. Set the web interface to record the video feed to its storage.

This would work; but you haven't specified if you own the server or not, what type of server it is, or whether you are on the same WiFi network as the phone.