# Upload video to another device during filming?

Tags: bluetooth, stock-android, video, file-transfer, wifi-direct

Here is the problem I am facing. If filming with a smartphone that doesn't come with a microsd card, you are severely limited by storage, especially if you want it shoot full HD video (on my phone that's 2.1-2.2 MB per second of footage). While it doesn't sound like much, I don't want to start deleting my apps and other pictures to fit the video footage (I have, at best, with stock apps only, about 10 GB of space, and I can't go around removing all my applications every time I need to video).

With that problem, I was wondering whether there is any way to transfer the video footage on the go to another computer (via Bluetooth or WiFi or even USB). Having searched all over the app store and other forums, I have not been able to find a solution, if it exists.

Tl Dr - is there an app / service that can transfer video files on the go to a secondary device, such that I am not limited to internal storage on a smartphone that does not have expansion options.

I have looked into other camera apps, xposed modules and even custom Roms but have not found anything that works just yet

Comment: Related: [Transferring continuous Android camera feed to PC through USB (in a background app/service)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/111443/96277), [Is it possible to write video directly to external device while recording](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/62281/96277)(not answered yet), [Record video and send it to server](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44439/96277).